Future tense Vs Future continuous tense and Continuous verbs used in Future Tense
a.When he comes to my house tomorrow, I will be writing a letter.
b.When he comes to my house tomorrow, I will write a letter.
Which of those sentences is correct? Or are both sentences right?If so, what's the difference?
By the way, in the structure using 'will do' to indicate the general future tense, can continuous verbs be used with phrases that denote a specific point in time? What is the semantic implication? Does it indicate that the continuous action begins at that point in time?
thanks!

The examples a and b mean different things.

As a comment says, they mean different things.
"When he comes to my house tomorrow, I will be writing a letter." Means that at the time of his arrival at my house tomorrow I will be in the process of writing a letter.
"When he comes to my house tomorrow, I will write a letter." Means that at some time after he arrives at my house tomorrow I will commence writing a letter.  Possibly immediately he arrives, conceivably even after he's left again.
